# How to find out, if ReentrantReadWriteLock's ReadLock is held before API Level 9

Tags: java, android, concurrency, reentrantreadwritelock

I noticed, that Java's `ReentrantReadWriteLock` is different in API versions <9 and >=9. Especially important for me, the method `getReadHoldCount()` isn't available in the older version.

Now my question is, how do I detect if a ReadLock is held by the current thread without this method? I only see the possibility of a manual counter or maybe a wrapper class, is there a built-in way to achieve this?

Comment: What were you planning to do if the lock isn't held by the current thread?

Comment: I was trying to implement something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/464824/615306