# Java ReadWriteLock Reentrance

Tags: java, multithreading, readwritelock, reentrantreadwritelock

Hi i have read about the ReadWriteLock in Java but i am not sure that i have grasped the reentrance part of it.
Here is two brief code examples using only one main thread to show reentrance

```
public class Locks {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        lock.readLock().lock();
        System.out.println( "Reentrance acheieved" );
        lock.readLock().unlock();
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

and the second example

```
public class Locks {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        lock.readLock().lock();
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        System.out.println( "Reentrance acheieved" );
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

In the first one the sysout is performed but not in the second one, why is that? Both locks are to be obtained by the same thread so we have a reentrance situation here, but the entrance is achieved only when writelock is obtained first which is strange because in non reentrant situation, the doc says that a write operation is exclusive with all the other operations (be it write or read).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java ReentrantReadWriteLocks - how to safely acquire write lock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464784/java-reentrantreadwritelocks-how-to-safely-acquire-write-lock)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is right there in the documentation under "Reentrancy":

> This lock allows both readers and writers to reacquire read or write
>   locks in the style of a ReentrantLock. Non-reentrant readers are not
>   allowed until all write locks held by the writing thread have been
>   released.
>
> Additionally, a writer can acquire the read lock, but not vice-versa.
>   Among other applications, reentrancy can be useful when write locks
>   are held during calls or callbacks to methods that perform reads under
>   read locks. **If a reader tries to acquire the write lock it will
>   never succeed.**